# Apex - Clone Parent and specific children

Tags: apex

I am trying to build an lwc that allows me to clone opportunities and their related products (custom object).  I am struggling to create the related products since I have to first insert the opportunities.  Below is my code where I am creating the opportunities (without issue) and at the bottom, I started working on creating the related opportunity_products__c.  I am unable to create the child records (opportunity products) under the cloned opportunities.  Thank you!!

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
public static List<opportunity> cloneOpps (List<Id> oppIds, id accountId, id brokerId, date effDate, string market, id ownerId, string cloneProducts){
    List<opportunity> existingopps = [select Id, Name, closeDate, recordTypeId, Whole_Segment__c, Employer_Contribution__c, Total_Eligible_Employees__c,
          Total_Employees_Enrolling__c, Incumbent_Carrier__c, Years_with_current_carrier__c, (select name, opportunity__c, status__c, Hsa_Hra__c, product_category__c,
          plan_design_category__c, pcmh_status__c, standard__c, Dependent__c, funding_arrangement__c, horizon_product__c, account__c from opportunity_products__r)from opportunity where id in : oppIds];
          
    List<opportunity> newOpps = new List<opportunity>();
    List<opportunity_products__c> newProds = new List<opportunity_products__c>();
    //loop opps and update close date
    for(opportunity opp : existingopps){
        //create variable for the cloned opportunity
        Opportunity clonedOpp = new Opportunity();
        clonedOpp = opp.clone(false, true, false, false);
        clonedOpp.RecordTypeId = opp.recordTypeId;
        clonedOpp.accountId = accountId;
        clonedOpp.OwnerId = ownerId;
        clonedOpp.CloseDate = effDate;
        clonedOpp.broker__c = brokerId;
        clonedOpp.StageName = 'Sales Proposal Prep';
        clonedOpp.Market_Segment__c = market;
        clonedOpp.Date_Received_Quote_Request__c = System.Today();
        newOpps.add(clonedOpp); 
  
    } // end of for statement
    String msg = '';
    try{
        insert newOpps;
    }
    catch(DmlException e){
        //Any type of Validation Rule error message, Required field missing error message, Trigger error message etc..
        //we can get from DmlException
       
        //Get All DML Messages
        for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
            //Get Validation Rule & Trigger Error Messages
            msg =+ e.getDmlMessage(i) +  '\n' ;
        }
        //throw DML exception message
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'in the DmlException and here is msg ' + msg);
        throw new AuraHandledException(msg);
       
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //throw all other exception message
        system.debug(logginglevel.info, 'in the Exception and here is e.getMessage() ' + e.getMessage());
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
    //This is what I am unsure of.. how do I get the related opportunity_products__c created under each newly created opportunity?
    for(opportunity opps : newOpps){
        Opportunity originalOpp = [select Id, Name, closeDate, recordTypeId, Whole_Segment__c, Employer_Contribution__c, Total_Eligible_Employees__c,
            Total_Employees_Enrolling__c, Incumbent_Carrier__c, Years_with_current_carrier__c, (select name, opportunity__c, status__c, Hsa_Hra__c, product_category__c,
            plan_design_category__c, pcmh_status__c, standard__c, Dependent__c, funding_arrangement__c, horizon_product__c, account__c from opportunity_products__r)from opportunity where              recordTypeId = : opps.recordTypeId];
  
    }
    return newOpps;
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: highlight your code and press the `{}` button in the editor to format a block of text as code. Alternatively, you can just put 3 backticks `\`\`\`` on their own line both above and below your code.

Comment: Plese [edit] your post to describe the specific issue / error you have, and what troubleshooting / research you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Id of the existing record as the key of a map. The value of the map would then be the cloned instance.

Due to the "store-by-reference" nature of collections, the cloned record in the map's values will get updated with the Id of the newly inserted record.

This can be chained to more than one level of child record.

The basic pattern would look like this

```java
List<Id> existingOppIds = ... //just assuming you get this data elsewhere

Map<Id, Opportunity> clonedOppsByOriginalId = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> clonedOLIsByOriginalId = new Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>();

// Do your cloning first
// The maps will help us set parents a bit later
for(Opportunity opp : [query here (with a subquery for OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :existingOppIds]) {
    clonedOppsByOriginalId.put(opp.Id, opp.clone());

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli : opp.OpportunityLineItems) {
        clonedOLIsByOriginalId.put(oli.Id, oli.clone());
    }
}

insert clonedOppsByOriginalId.values();

// Now that the cloned opps have been inserted and have Ids, we can fetch
//   them and set the new Id on the child records before inserting them
for(OpportunityLineItem oli : clonedOLIsByOriginalId.values()) {
    // I'd just use the .get() to directly set oli.OpportunityId in practice
    // Breaking it out into multiple statements here for clarity
    Id originalOppId = oli.OpportunityId;
    Id clonedOppId = clonedOppsByOriginalId.get(originalOppId).Id;

    oli.OpportunityId = clonedOppId;
}

insert clonedOLIsByOriginalId.values();
```

Adjust to suit your needs